# How to properly alter response from Solr Search Module

Tags: 7, search

I'm working on `Drupal Version 7.22` and I'm trying to modify the results coming from Solr using the hook provided by the [Solr Search Module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr).

The specific hook can be found here: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api_solr!search_api_solr.api.php/function/hook_search_api_solr_search_results_alter/7

Here's how I implemented it from the module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_solr_search_results_alter().
 */
function zen_search_api_solr_search_results_alter(array &$results, SearchApiQueryInterface $query, Apache_Solr_Response $response){


  $locations = array();  

  $rest = $results['results'];
  foreach($rest as $r){

    $place = $r['fields']['field_business_name'];
    $postal_code =  urlencode($r['fields']['field_business_address:postal_code']);

    $api = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' .  $postal_code . '&sensor=false';
    $api_results = file_get_contents($api);
        $data = json_decode($api_results, true);

        if($data['status'] == 'OK'){
            $location = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];

            $locations[] = array(
                'place' => $place,
                'lat' => $location['lat'],
                'lng' => $location['lng']
            );      
        }

  }

    $data = array('zen' => array('locations' => $locations));
    drupal_add_js($data, 'setting');

}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do here is to add the coordinates that I get from the Google  maps Geo-coding API using `drupal_add_js`.

But I'm getting the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to
>   zen_search_api_solr_search_results_alter() must be an
>   instance of Apache_Solr_Response, instance of stdClass given

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was this one:

```
function zen_search_api_solr_search_results_alter(array &$results, SearchApiQueryInterface $query, Apache_Solr_Response $response){
  ...
}
```

It should be this:

```
function zen_search_api_solr_search_results_alter(&$results, $query, $response){
  ...
}
```